# How to configure YML file when used TestNG & in that used more than one classes?

Tags: jmeter

I created a Maven project I used TestNG. Here in programming I used two classes one base class and another derived class and call all methods. Now I want to convert it to JMX so I used the Taurus tool and for conversion used a proxy recorder. Now I want to configure yml file. Here I used two classes then How is it configured?
and Here I used TestNG so which external files/paths need to be added?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Maven dependency plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) to download all the transitive dependencies:

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

it will download all the .jar files required to run your project.

Once done you can use [`additional-classpath` directive](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JUnit/#Configuration-Options) to "tell" Taurus where the .jar files live:

```
scenarios:
  testng-file:
    script: yourTest.java
    additional-classpath:
    - dependency1.jar
    - dependency2.jar
    - etc.
```

If you have already performed the conversion you can existing .jmx script either by directly providing it as a parameter for `bzt`

```
bzt your-test-script.jmx
```

or if you want to use [Taurus YAML file](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Run-Existing-JMX-File)

```
execution:
- scenario: simple

scenarios:
  simple:
    script: your-test-script.jmx
```

More information: [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus)